# Spark with BloomFilter of billions of records causes Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bloom-filter, bigdata

I have used Breeze implementation of Bloom filter in Apache spark. My Bloom Filter expects 200,000,000 keys.But i am facing below exception:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 161, SVDG0752.ideaconnect.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 1
```

I know to avoid this I can increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value but due to the cluster resource limitations i can't increase it more than 2GB.

Below Is The Code:

```
val numOfBits=2147483647
val numOfHashFun=13
val bf = hierachyMatching.treeAggregate(new BloomFilter[String](numOfBits,numOfHashFun))(
  _ += _, _ |= _)
```

where hierachyMatching is the Rdd of type String containing 200M records.

My Questions:

- How can i tackle this exception without increasing buffer.max value and How?
- Is It possible to construct a bloom filter that contains more than 2billion bits on spark with the driver memory 6512mb and How?

Any ideas or suggestions related to this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` to `1 gb` (or make experiment with this property so select better value) in `spark-default.conf` (or overridden properties) and restart your spark service, it should help you.

Comment: I have already tried giving spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max size upto 2gb (in execution parameters), But still it is giving me same exception and i cant increase it more than 2gb.

Comment: @mayur try to use property `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb` and value `512`

Comment: still not working. If it is not working with 2gb then how will it work with just 512mb?

Comment: @mayur it means that the allocated size for kryoserializer buffer was not enough for the amount of data which you process

Comment: yes exactly. And I want workaround for the same. I doubt i am using the tree aggregate correctly with bloom filter.

Comment: 2147483647 bits means  around 268 mb memory. still 2gb is not enough. I don't know what overhead it added when serializing bloom filter of  2147483647 bits

Answer (score 0):

There are to properties:
`spark.kryoserializer.buffer` and `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max`

You need to specify both of them, for instance, `--conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer=10m --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2000m`